# Module of differentials of an extension of Dedekind domains

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain with fraction field $K$, $L|K$ a finite separable field extension and $B$ the integral closure of $A$ in $L$. Assume that al the residue field extensions are separable. In the proof of Serre's "Local Fields", chapter III, Proposition 14 (page 59), it is stated that in order to show that the module of differentials $\Omega_{B|A}$ is cyclic we can assume that $A$ is local and complete. Why?

I understand the reduction to the local case of the other part of the theorem (the annihilator of the module of differentials equals the Dedekind different), since clearly two ideals are equal if they are locally equal, but being cyclic is not a local property in general, and I am not able to understand that reduction to the local case.

For convenience the above Proposition is the following:

[image]

Comment: Maybe there is no general local-to-global principle, but finitely generated modules over a Dedekind domain decomposes as a direct sum of free modules and cyclic modules. Could that not help?

Comment: Thank you. Indeed it follows from the structure of finitely generated modules over Dedekind domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Omega_{B|A}$ is a finitely generated $B$-module, and we know it is locally cyclic and annihilated by the different.  In particular, this means it is a finitely generated torsion $B$-module, so since $B$ is a Dedekind domain, it is a direct sum $\bigoplus B/p_i^{n_i}$ for primes $p_i$.  Now since it is locally cyclic, the $p_i$ must all be distinct (if a prime $p$ appeared twice among the $p_i$, the localization at $p$ would not be cyclic).  It now follows from the Chinese remainder theorem that $\Omega_{B|A}\cong \bigoplus B/p_i^{n_i} \cong B/\prod p_i^{n_i}$ so it is cyclic.

Comment: Thank you. However I wonder if there is another way to see it, since Serre's book studies Dedeking domains from the very definition and does not treat the structure of finitely generated modules over a Dedekind domain. As soon as I have enough reputation I will vote up.

Comment: It seems you have mixed $A$ and $B$ in your answer: $\Omega_{B/A}$ is supposed to be cyclic as a $B$-module, not as an $A$-module. But of course, your argument still works.

Comment: @FlorianAdler: Oops, thanks, I've corrected that!